# InstallShield does not install VC++ redistributable on install

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield, redistributable

Using VS2012 to build the setup file and have VC++ redis 2012 as a requirement and when I go to run the installer, it does not prompt the user to install the package. I double checked that I have it selected in the redistributables section. I also made sure it wasn't already installed on the machine attempting to install it.

Not sure why Installshield isn't prompting for the install.

Comment: Run your installer with `/debuglog` and examine the resulting log file for information on why the prerequisite does or does not run. That may give a better pointer on what to change.

Answer (score 1):

Open the InstallShield IDE.  Under 'Application  Data' click on 'Redistributables'.  Find the desired redistributable in the window on the right and right-click on it.  If that one allows you to do so, select 'Edit Prerequisite' and look through the tabs.  Verify that 'Conditions' and 'Behavior' are correct.

Answer (score 1):

For checked what is the problem that no let you install you prerequisite, try this:

1. When you generate you installer be sure that in the installer folder there is a folder with the installer of the prerequisite.
2. Execute individually the prerequisite installer (generated by installshield) in the target machine.

In my case I tried to install .Net Framework 4.5 in windows XP, when I executed this installer in the target machine this showed me an error "this frameowrk is not compatible with this system"